# showing syntax error for a simple javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const fee = t.transaction_info.hasOwnProperty("fee_amount")
          ? -t.transaction_info?.fee_amount?.value
          : 0;
```

showing:

```
? -t.transaction_info?.fee_amount?.value
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Comment: Make sure you are using a `node.js` version that supports optional chaining.

Comment: What is the output of your `node --version` ?  (Pretty sure this was implemented in node 14, i.e. 13 or lower won't have it.)